# How to use combobox items as numbers to add the instances these items are used?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a combobox with items "Regular Holiday" and "Special Non-Working Holiday" which is included in my datagridview. I just want to ask if I can add their values as numbers (the instances that the combobox items were used) so I could place the sum on my listview. This is in C#.

Comment: What you are asking is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string TotalHoliday()
    {
        int RegHD = 0;
        int SpclHD = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.IsNewRow) break;
            object HD = row.Cells["Holidays"].Value;
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(HD) && HD != null && HD.ToString() == "Regular")
            {
                RegHD++;
            }
            else if (!Convert.IsDBNull(HD) && HD != null && HD.ToString() == "Special Non-working")
            {
                SpclHD++;
            }
        }

        int totHD = RegHD + SpclHD;
        string totalHD = totHD.ToString();
        return totalHD;
    }
```

I had already figured this one out. Anyway, thank you for having a time to answer my problem. I appreciate it.